# gpload port already in use?

Tags: greenplum

I am using gpload with yaml formatted script. Additionally I am using a before+after SQL script. I have always used the port 8100 for previous gpload, and my data has been loading successfully. I am not sure why I am getting the following error:

```
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] Before opening listening sockets - following listening sockets are available:
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] IPV6 socket: [::]:8081
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] IPV4 socket: 0.0.0.0:8081
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] Trying to open listening socket:
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] IPV6 socket: [::]:8081
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] [WRN gpfdist.c:2094] Address already in use (errno = 98), port: 8081
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] Trying to open listening socket:
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] IPV4 socket: 0.0.0.0:8081
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] [WRN gpfdist.c:2094] Address already in use (errno = 98), port: 8081
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: 
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] Before opening listening sockets - following listening sockets are available:
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] IPV6 socket: [::]:8082
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] IPV4 socket: 0.0.0.0:8082
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] Trying to open listening socket:
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] IPV6 socket: [::]:8082
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] [WRN gpfdist.c:2094] Address already in use (errno = 98), port: 8082
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] Trying to open listening socket:
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] IPV4 socket: 0.0.0.0:8082
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] [WRN gpfdist.c:2094] Address already in use (errno = 98), port: 8082
2016-11-14 11:04:04|LOG|gpfdist says: [2016-11-14 11:04:04] [INTERNAL ERROR gpfdist.c:2138] cannot create socket on port 8082 (last port is 8082)
```

Any takers?

Comment: Check to see if gpfdist is still running: ps -ef  | grep gpfdist | grep -v grep   .  You can also use PORT_RANGE in the yml file for gpload rather than just a single port.

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is still persisting. I have eliminated the ports which give the error "port is in use" and tried other ranges